# JS | Get return from sub Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, pouchdb

I need to get the return of a sub function.

So i have the following Code and need the result of `doc` in the Parent function, additionally i want to return an Array so i need to copy the Array because the parent array will be deleted after the sub process has been closed?

Thank you for your Time!

```js
function test(){
    var HereINeedTheArray []
    db.allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: true}, function(err, doc) {
       HereINeedTheArray = doc
       return doc //can i get this return or do i need HereINeedTheArray? 
    })
}
```

Comment: Looks async to me.  Think of it this way, `test` initiates some process (db.allDocs), which will take some time to complete, so rather than wait for it to finish, we say “here’s a function to run when it’s done” (the callback, which you refer to as sub function).  But test has long since returned when that happens.  So you should do whatever it is you were planning on doing with the returned result *inside the callback*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function performs an asynchronous call to the database, thus you can not return the result in a synchronous fashion. You have to handle the returned value in the callback:

```
function test(){
    var HereINeedTheArray []
    db.allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: true}, function(err, doc) {
       // logic to handle doc here
    })
}
```

Or you can [Promisify](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwifqMWVwLfXAhVDa1AKHW7-CGEQFggtMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fit%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FPromise&usg=AOvVaw2Jjg1aia2yKLh3bfMwkmRr) your function:

```
function test(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: true}, function(err, doc) {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            resolve(doc);           
        });
    });
}

test.then(function(doc) {
    // handle doc here
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // handle error
});
```

Or you can use [async/await](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_7aSWwbfXAhVRJVAKHRTcC3kQFgg7MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Fasync_function&usg=AOvVaw0euFq37zE3YIIpKHqoNwmt) if you are on [node.js](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwii3-K0wbfXAhWIZlAKHarNDjEQFggtMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnodejs.org%2Fit%2F&usg=AOvVaw2LQGmSr_7GxS6vusU0coxi) >= 7.6 or have [Babel transpiling with ES2017](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2017/):

```
function _test(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: true}, function(err, doc) {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            resolve(doc);           
        });
    });
}

async function test() {
    let doc = await _test();
    // handle doc here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const test = ()=>{
  const HereINeedTheArray = []
  db.allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: true}, function(err, doc) {
   HereINeedTheArray.push(doc)
   return HereINeedTheArray
  })
}
```

Comment: This is Working! - here is the FIXED Version https://jsfiddle.net/19rL0w41/   thank you!

Comment: why are you using const instead of function?

Comment: Im using the ES6 "fat arrow syntax ()=>", its a shorthand for function creations with a few differences.